# Android parsing 2 jsonarray

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I wanna parse 2 JasonArray. I don't use listview, i use spinner and textboxes to show data.

this is where my information is

```
public class Config {
//JSON URL
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://bitirmeprojem.tk/data.php";

//Tags used in the JSON String
public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "Ders_Ad";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "Ders_Ad";
public static final String TAG_HOCA = "Hoca_Ad";
//public static final String TAG_SESSION = "session";

//JSON array name
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "users";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY2 = "hoca";
}
```

and this is where i parse it:

```
private void getData(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students   from the JSON Array
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I tried to create `getData2()`,  but it crashes the app.

What else i can do?

Comment: why haven't you parsed your array further?

Comment: @VivekMishra i didn't get what you mention. I tried to create new JsonObject , and used it for the other array, in the getData(). But it didn't worked, it crashes the app.

Comment: json at http://bitirmeprojem.tk/data.php is not valid, you can check it at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ . also what does logcat say about the crash?

Comment: Post your crash log. Is your `Config.DATA_URL` is returning two JSON arrays??

Comment: your API http://bitirmeprojem.tk/data.php response is not valid.

Comment: You have an invalid JSON Data.

Comment: Check here http://jsonlint.com/ your `Json` is Invalid.

Comment: @DevrimTuncer sir, can i have your any social media profile ? for asking properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this json Response.**

`Setup this valid json response in your API.`

```
{
    "users": [{
        "Ders_Ad": "E-Ticaret"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Yapay Zeka"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Mant\u0131ksal Devre Tasar\u0131m\u0131"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Programlama Dilleri"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Bilgisayar Mimarisi"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Veri \u0130leti\u015fimi"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Bilgisayar A\u011flar\u0131"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Veritaban\u0131 Sistemleri"
    }],

    "hoca": [{
        "Ders_Ad": "E-Ticaret"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Yapay Zeka"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Mant\u0131ksal Devre Tasar\u0131m\u0131"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Programlama Dilleri"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Bilgisayar Mimarisi"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Veri \u0130leti\u015fimi"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Bilgisayar A\u011flar\u0131"
    }, {
        "Ders_Ad": "Veritaban\u0131 Sistemleri"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "R\u0131fat",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Yaz\u0131c\u0131"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "Metin",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Turan"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "Mustafa Cem",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Kasapba\u015f\u0131"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "Mustafa Cem",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Kasapba\u015f\u0131"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "R\u0131fat",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Yaz\u0131c\u0131"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "Halim",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Zaim"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "Halim",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Zaim"
    }, {
        "Hoca_Ad": "Metin",
        "Hoca_Soyad": "Turan"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your Api gives you response like this

```
{"users":[{"Ders_Ad":"E-Ticaret"},{"Ders_Ad":"Yapay Zeka"},{"Ders_Ad":"Mant\u0131ksal Devre Tasar\u0131m\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Programlama Dilleri"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar Mimarisi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veri \u0130leti\u015fimi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar A\u011flar\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veritaban\u0131 Sistemleri"}]}{"hoca":[{"Ders_Ad":"E-Ticaret"},{"Ders_Ad":"Yapay Zeka"},{"Ders_Ad":"Mant\u0131ksal Devre Tasar\u0131m\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Programlama Dilleri"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar Mimarisi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veri \u0130leti\u015fimi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar A\u011flar\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veritaban\u0131 Sistemleri"},{"Hoca_Ad":"R\u0131fat","Hoca_Soyad":"Yaz\u0131c\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Metin","Hoca_Soyad":"Turan"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Mustafa Cem","Hoca_Soyad":"Kasapba\u015f\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Mustafa Cem","Hoca_Soyad":"Kasapba\u015f\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"R\u0131fat","Hoca_Soyad":"Yaz\u0131c\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Halim","Hoca_Soyad":"Zaim"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Halim","Hoca_Soyad":"Zaim"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Metin","Hoca_Soyad":"Turan"}]}
```

but actual valid for JSON Format like this

```
{"users":[{"Ders_Ad":"E-Ticaret"},{"Ders_Ad":"Yapay Zeka"},{"Ders_Ad":"Mant\u0131ksal Devre Tasar\u0131m\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Programlama Dilleri"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar Mimarisi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veri \u0130leti\u015fimi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar A\u011flar\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veritaban\u0131 Sistemleri"}], "hoca":[{"Ders_Ad":"E-Ticaret"},{"Ders_Ad":"Yapay Zeka"},{"Ders_Ad":"Mant\u0131ksal Devre Tasar\u0131m\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Programlama Dilleri"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar Mimarisi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veri \u0130leti\u015fimi"},{"Ders_Ad":"Bilgisayar A\u011flar\u0131"},{"Ders_Ad":"Veritaban\u0131 Sistemleri"},{"Hoca_Ad":"R\u0131fat","Hoca_Soyad":"Yaz\u0131c\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Metin","Hoca_Soyad":"Turan"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Mustafa Cem","Hoca_Soyad":"Kasapba\u015f\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Mustafa Cem","Hoca_Soyad":"Kasapba\u015f\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"R\u0131fat","Hoca_Soyad":"Yaz\u0131c\u0131"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Halim","Hoca_Soyad":"Zaim"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Halim","Hoca_Soyad":"Zaim"},{"Hoca_Ad":"Metin","Hoca_Soyad":"Turan"}]}
```